# oracle sql - show both sides of a relation

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table:

```
Location:
STORE  LINK_STORE
100      null
200      100
300      100
```

100 is the parent store and 200/300 are child stores

I want to show data in this form:

```
STORE    TYPE     REF_STORE
100      PARENT      200
100      PARENT      300
200      CHILD       100
300      CHILD       100
```

how to repeat the ROW for parent store

Comment: Do join with the same table: `from Location as p left join location as c on c.ref_store = p.store`

Comment: I changed your title, because a `CROSS JOIN` is a join without any condition, so that was misleading. If you don't like the new title, you can change it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this using a lateral join:

```
select x.*
from t cross join lateral
     (select link_store as store, 'PARENT' as type, store as ref_store from dual union all
      select store, 'CHILD', link_store from dual
     ) x
where link_store is not null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNION ALL`:

```sql
SELECT link_store AS store,
       'PARENT' AS type,
       store AS ref_store
FROM   location
WHERE  link_store IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT store,
       'CHILD',
       link_store
FROM   location
WHERE  link_store IS NOT NULL
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Location (STORE, LINK_STORE) AS
SELECT 100, null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 200, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 300, 100 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | STORE | TYPE | REF_STORE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 100 | PARENT | 200 |
> | 100 | PARENT | 300 |
> | 200 | CHILD | 100 |
> | 300 | CHILD | 100 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2d663c012f27e113f17d52bba965d044)*

Comment: By far the best solution in my opinion. Why join, when all the data is already there in the existing rows?

Answer (score 0):

Use a self `FULL` join and a `CASE` expression to get the column `TYPE`:

```
SELECT l1.STORE, 
       CASE WHEN l1.LINK_STORE IS NULL THEN 'PARENT' ELSE 'CHILD' END TYPE,
       COALESCE(l1.LINK_STORE, l2.STORE) REF_STORE
FROM Location l1 FULL JOIN Location l2
ON l2.LINK_STORE = l1.STORE
WHERE l1.STORE IS NOT NULL;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=70850230ddd1a7ccbae8c2f1db0e61b7).